# Significant visual differences between jpeg and webp

Tags: webp

The sample image given by Google with the WebpCodecSetup.exe and those I created with cwebp is significantly darker than the corresponding jpeg image when I open it with Windows Photo Viewer (also set up to open .webp images by WebpCodecSetup.exe).

This visual difference does not exist when opened in chrome.

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCrrM.jpg)
[Windows Photo Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O1WM.jpg)

Can I reasonably conclude that Windows Photo Viewer / WebpCodecSetup.exe is causing the problem? If so, is there any solutions or alternatives to windows photo viewer if I would like to view webp files without a browser?